# Taylor Series of Complex Integral

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm having some trouble deriving a Taylor series around z=0 and its radius of convergence for the function $f(z)=\int_{0}^{z} e^{t^{2}} dt$.

I've calculated the first few derivatives at $z=0$ as $1,0,2,0,12,...$ but I haven't been able to find a pattern other than it being zero on even powers.  Has anyone had any experience with this function?  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(0) = 0\\
f'(z) = e^{z^2}$

$e^z = \sum \frac {z^n}{n!}\\
e^{z^2} = \sum \frac {(z^2)^n}{n!} = \sum \frac {z^{2n}}{n!}$

$f(z) = $$f(0) + \int \sum \frac {z^{2n}}{n!} dz\\
\sum_\limits{n=0}^\infty \frac {z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)n!}$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $f(z)$ is an antiderivative of $e^{z^2}$ on the whole complex plane. Hence $f$ is an entire function, and its Taylor series converges for every $z$.

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that $f(z)$ is the [imaginary error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Imaginary_error_function), that is,

$$f(z)=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\operatorname{erfi}(z)$$

This has a [well known Maclaurin expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function#Taylor_series), which follows from the fact that $e^z=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^n}{n!}$.  Indeed, it follows basically from Doug's answer that

$$\frac{\sqrt\pi}2\operatorname{erfi}(z)=\sum _{n=0}^\infty\frac{z^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}=z-\frac {z^{3}}{3}+\frac {z^{5}}{10}+\frac {z^{7}}{42}+\frac {z^{9}}{216}+\ \cdots$$